# Overriding default keyword analysis for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to configure an elasticsearch index to have a default indexing policy of analysis with the `keyword` analyzer, and then overriding it on some fields, to allow them to be free text analyzed. So effectively opt-in free text analysis, where I am explicitly specifying in the mapping which fields are analysed for free text matching. My mapping defintion looks like this:

```
PUT test_index
{
   "mappings":{
      "test_type":{
         "index_analyzer":"keyword",
         "search_analyzer":"standard",
         "properties":{
            "standard":{
               "type":"string",
               "index_analyzer":"standard"
            },
            "keyword":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So `standard` should be an analyzed field, and `keyword` should be exact match only. However when I insert some sample data with the following command:

```
POST test_index/test_type
{
  "standard":"a dog in a rug",
  "keyword":"sheepdog"
}
```

I am not getting any matches against the following query:

```
GET test_index/test_type/_search?q=dog
```

However I *do* get matches against:

```
GET test_index/test_type/_search?q=*dog*
```

Which makes me think that the `standard` field is not being analyzed. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with the index created. Change your query to `GET test_index/test_type/_search?q=standard:dog` and it should return the expected results.

If you do not want to specify field name in the query, update your mapping such that you provide the `index_analyzer` and `search_analyzer` values explicitly for each field with no default values. See below:

```
PUT test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "test_type": {
         "properties": {
            "standard": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "standard",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "keyword": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "keyword",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now if you try `GET test_index/test_type/_search?q=dog`, you'll get the desired results.

Comment: I'm trying to get the behaviour back where I don't need to specify the search fields. Fields may be added at any time, and it won't be possible to add the new field names to every query when that occurs.